# Best approach to integrate netty with openshift

Tags: jboss, playframework, redhat, netty, openshift

In fact, I'm trying to see which would be the best approach to achieve play framework native support on openshift.

Play has it's own http server developed with netty. Right now you can deploy a play application to openshift, but you have to deploy it as a war, in which case play uses Servlet Container wrapper.

Being able to deploy it as a netty application would allow us to use some advanced features, like asynchronuos request.

Openshift uses jboss, so this question would also involve which would be the recommended approach to deploy a netty application on a jboss server, using netty instead of the servlet container provided by jboss.

Here is [request for providing play framework native support on openshift](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/content/native-support-for-play-framework-application) There's more info there, and if you like it you can also add your vote ;-)

Comment: Have you tried Play on Heroku?

Comment: Of course I've tried, james, and it's great... but unfortunately heroku's free offering is a bit restrictive, openshift gives you five apps with half GB each... BTW, was it too difficult to adapt play to jetty???

Comment: Cool.  Is that a half GB or disk space?  By default on Heroku, Play apps just use their embedded Netty server instead of Jetty or Tomcat.

Comment: It's half GB disk space (code + data) for each app, and if you have a cool project and talk to them they can even raise it... BTW, I'll have a look at your heroku module to do the same with openshift, I've already started with a python version, I'm planning to do a next version all with java - have a look at this: http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/play-framework-on-the-cloud-made-easy-openshift-module/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with creating 'raw-0.1' application.

SSH into the server and

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
```

download and install play into a directory here. $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is supposed to survive redeploys of your application.

Now you can disconnect from SSH.

Clone the application repository. In the repository, there is a file .openshift/actions_hooks/start. It's task is to start the application using a framework of your choice. The file will need to contain at least (from what I know about Play)

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/play-directroy/play run --http.port=$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT --some-other-parameters
```

**Important**

- You have to bind to $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP:$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT. Trying to bind to different interface is not allowed, also most of the ports are blocked.
- To create some sort of template, save the installation steps into .openshift/action_hooks/build file. Check if play is installed, if it is do nothing, if it's not, execute the installation process.

Comment: great! I'll give it a try... I saw raw cartridge a couple of days ago, but didn't know quite well what was it about... (ok, I should have guessed...)

Comment: You may take a look at this https://github.com/marekjelen/openshift-jruby for inspiration ... it's a template for running JRuby applications on raw-0.1 on OpenShift.